# django: How to add a dynamic variable to an address in HTML?

Tags: html, django

I need to put a dynamic variable into an address on a form in django.
The form is:

```
<form action='/disciplinas/{{disciplina_id}}/edit/' method='submit'>{% csrf_token %}
<input type='submit' value='Voltar'>
</form>
```

The problem is at the "action" where I wrote "{{disciplina_id}}", how could I represent that?

view.py function

```
def detail(request, disciplina_id):
  nome = disciplina.objects.filter(id__exact=disciplina_id)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    return HttpResponseRedirect('^(?P<disciplina_id>\d+)')
  if request.method == 'POST':
    nome.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/disciplinas/success')
  return render_to_response('/home/zephir/Template/disciplinas/detail.html', {'nome': nome}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: update your post with your view function in views.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constructing urls which map to particular views in the template is done with the `url` template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to inject context variables into your template.

```
def my_view(request, disciplina_id):
    nome = disciplina.objects.get(id__exact=disciplina_id)
    return render_to_response('/home/zephir/Template/disciplinas/detail.html', {'nome': nome, 'disciplina_id': disciplina_id}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

See that dictionary? That contains the map of variables available to your template. Or more simply:

```
def my_view(request, disciplina_id):
    nome = disciplina.objects.get(id__exact=disciplina_id)
    return render_to_response('/home/zephir/Template/disciplinas/detail.html', {'nome': nome}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

<form action='/disciplinas/{{nome.id}}/edit/' method='submit'>{% csrf_token %}
    <input type='submit' value='Voltar'>
</form>
```

Since you're already passing through the `disciplina` instance, just access its `id` property within your template.

I've intentionally avoided commenting on the structure of your view (two checks for `method=='POST'`), but you might want to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing nome object to template you should refer itsd attributes by its name as follows,

```
<form action='/disciplinas/{{nome.disciplina_id}}/edit/' method='submit'>{% csrf_token %}
<input type='submit' value='Voltar'>
</form>
```